# Error Undefined index con validador de cedula chilena

Tags: php, woocommerce, undefined

Instale un plugin para validar el número de identificación chileno en los datos del checkout de WooCommerce, pero al inactivar la condición para que el campo sea obligatorio, se presenta el siguiente mensaje en el debug.log

*PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rut_not_required in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rut-chileno-con-validacion/includes/class-wc-chilean-bundle-logic.php on line 18*

Aclaro que en el checkout al inactivar este campo, la página me permite digitar el número y continuar con la compra en la pasarela de pagos del proveedor sin problemas. Pero quisiera saber si este mensaje afecta o no. Y si me recomiendan alguna solución

Comment: Si estas usando "WooCommerce" deberias ponerlo en las etiquetas

Comment: Precisamente es para woocommerce, me explicarias como hacer lo que dices?

Comment: Puedes [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/448483/edit) tu pregunta y agregar es etiqueta. Esta opcion aparece en la parte inferior de tu pregunta

Comment: Mi opinión... no deberías ignorar los `Notice` y yo los corregiría ... ¿por qué? porque nunca se sabe, alguna vez puede que se deban a **un error de tipeo**, o realmente necesites que si este definida dicha variable y no se esta enviando, etc. Por algo existen estos mensajes de error...